# My Skyrim SE won't start via SKSE?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have few mods installled in my Skyrim SE (maybe around 50) and when I try to run my Skyrim Special Edition via SKSE launcher it just show me a black screen with a cursor spining and after a while it says "Not Responding."

How can I make my Skyrim SE run via SKSE as I used to do always?

Comment: Have you optimized your mod load order? What changes have you made since it last worked? (Also 50 is a bit more than "a few"...)

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Hi I just installed some armor mods thats all. Should I past here my load order too?

Comment: No don't paste that here. Have you run LOOT/optimized your load order? If you remove those new mods you added, does it work?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I forgot to say I updated my Vortex ( mod installer from Nexus Mods) Do you think it can be problem there?

Comment: Vortex is just a vehicle for mods, and doesn't do anything beyond downloading and organizing load orders. Roddy's suggestion is right in that you should run LOOT / find a way to optimize your load order. Mods will conflict and stop things from running. SKSE is not likely the culprit, unless you have an outdated version of SKSE vs. your Skyrim version.

Comment: @nightsurfer thanks for clarification. I already resolved it with that LOOT program :) But I have other question if I may ask? I am trying to `write some cheats into console` but it only shows me `squares like this  [][][][][][]` instead of alphabets. Do you have Idea how to fix this ? Thanx

Comment: @Leviathan the comments aren't the right spot for additional questions, partly because the character limit doesn't allow for extended detail. I'd recommend making a new post for that question :)

Comment: Armor mods CTDs are usually a bad mesh. LOOT fixed your load order problem, but you really should start from scratch with Mod Organiser. .... "[Try reinstalling Sky UI or any font mods you have. Change the "Region" to "English USA"]." https://steamcommunity.com/app/72850/discussions/0/141136086935645323/

Comment: @nightsurfer Hi here it is : https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/397191/tes-v-skyrim-se-problem-with-cheat-codes-doesnt-show-letters