# Console commands don't show up as letters, but as square symbols

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have a problem with in-game console commands in *TES V: Skyrim Special Edition*, where instead of letters, it only types as square boxes. They look something like this `□□□□□□`. I have also installed like 50 mods but I am not sure what causes the issue.

[image: Screenshot of the problem in game]

Comment: One of your mods is a font mod with files missing/conflicting I think. If you have installed something like Sovngarde - A Nordic Font or any other custom fonts and something is conflicting with it check their patches section.

Comment: @LoreFriendly Hi only have SkyUI ... May there be a problem?

Comment: Is your language for Skyrim not English, or at one time was not English?

Comment: @nightsurfer true when I installed it there was russian language by default so I have to change it .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is usally an issue with languages. One possible fix is go to Skyrim.ini (usually located at Documents/My Games/Skyrim) and delete the following line:

[Fonts]
sFontConfigFile=Interface\FontConfig_ru.txt

Some other possible fixes are to change your system language to English US if it isn't already or to check if any mods have language settings and set them to English.

Comment: Hi **Deleting line**  `[Fonts] sFontConfigFile=Interface\FontConfig_ru.txt` in Skyrim.ini **solved my problem**