# SKSE64_Loader won't start the game

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, technical-issues, mods

For some reason when I try to boot my game (which worked fine a minute ago), I get the following instead (also see image below):

> `SHGetFolderPath 00000005 failed (result = 80070005 lasterr = 00000005)`
>
> `Assertion failed in E: \github\common\common\IDebugLog.cpp (64): SUCCEEDED(err) (code - FFFFFFFF80070005 (-2147024891))`

Can anyone tell me why this is happening, and/or what this means and (hopefully) how to fix it?

What I have tried so far:

- Checked the firewall and the antivirus software.
- Run as admin.
- Re-installed everything around 4 times, including the game and SKSE64.
- Checked mod conflicts.
- Disabled controlled folder access.

PS when it started acting up, I had just wiped my keyboard real quick and I hit a couple of buttons and then the black screen came up and now it won't work.

[image: A Screenshot of the command window thing that pops up]

Comment: Google says that SHGetFolderPath is a function which tries to find "well known folders" such as My Documents (or Documents, on newer versions of Windows), and 80070005 is an ACCESS DENIED error. Skyrim does create/use files under Documents, so that is a plausible failure mode. Did you change the permissions on the Documents (or My Documents) folder?

Comment: im not sure. how would i change the permission? and what would i need to change it to so it works?

Comment: @Jim Hi I asked same question here https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/397161/my-skyrim-se-wont-start-via-skse . Check there if you find there anything useful. Maybe try to check Skyrim.ini there can be a problem. I can see there is problem with your IDebugLog but I am not sure if it is mod or part of original game. If it is a mod then try to disable it and then try tu run your game. Also always use Vortex to install your mods  .

Comment: [F4SE not launching Error code: FFFFFFFF80070005](https://www.reddit.com/r/f4se/comments/trtjsb/f4se_not_launching_error_code_ffffffff80070005/) "Update:The problem was malwarantibytes blocking access to the documents folder"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so i wish i could say what i did but the game and skse just started working again some time ago. really sorry if someone else has the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

This might indicate that the SKSE Loader does not or no longer has access to folders where it needs to write files (like `E:\github\common\common\`).

Look for 'Controlled Folder Access' under Start (by opening the Start menu and typing in the words). Either turn it off, or give *skse64_loader.exe* full access by using the '*Allow an app through controlled folder access*' option:

[image: Windows 10 Ransomware protection menu]

What could have caused this is a silent update of Microsoft Defender.